# Can't access rabbitmq outside of localhost (windows)

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I've set up everything properly and I can do everything from the localhost (where rabbitmq broker is) but I get no response from other machines on the port..

How can I enable rabbitmq to accept connections from everywhere?

Comment: @SLaks man thanks so much, I have a node server on the same machine and for some reason I can access it, so I didn't even consider firewall being an issue

Comment: Firewalls block _external_ connections.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for the response.. I don't get it that though. If node is running, it opens a port, and waits for connections to come through. Isn't that the same for rabbitmq? It opens a port on 5672 and waits for connections. I'm not very experienced with this stuff

Comment: Yes; it is the same.  In both cases, the firewall will prevent other computers from connecting to that port.  You probably already had a firewall hole for Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the firewall, thanks to @SLaks comment